# Report footer textbox SUM displays empty value instead of number

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have have a Tablix with cells containing value expression using Group Variables (i.e. `Variables!varTotalBudget.Value`).

I have a Report Footer with 9 textboxes, each doing a SUM on the Tablix textboxes (i.e. `Sum(ReportItems!TotalBudget.Value)`).

The Report Footer SUM is totaling the values correctly on all but one column.  I can’t figure out why.

Anyone have any idea why the values will not SUM in “Future Outlay” footer textbox? I have tried a few different things and I continue to get an empty value instead of the expected number aggregate.  I have tried forcing the datatypes (i.e. `CDbl()`) and I have tried checking for empty values and converting to 0 number.  The textbox has font color “black” so I know it’s not invisible. The last column in image below is formatted as General format () but it was formatted number (`#,0.00;(#,0.00)`) same as the others; I changed it to general to inspect the value to see if it was blank but it appears to be a zero value. I'm not sure why the SUM is blank. Any ideas?

[image]

These are the variables involved in the problem textbox.

```
<Variables>
  <Variable Name="varTotalBudget">
    <Value>=CDbl(Lookup(Fields!ProjectId.Value, Fields!ACTIVITY.Value, Fields!TOTAL_BUDGET.Value, "dsActivityBudgets")) </Value>
  </Variable>
  <Variable Name="varBudgetVariance">
    <Value>=Variables!varTotalBudget.Value - Variables!varExpenditureLifetime.Value </Value>
  </Variable>
   <Variable Name="varProjectFutureOutlay">
    <Value>=IIF(Variables!varBudgetVariance.Value < 0, 0, Variables!varBudgetVariance.Value) </Value>
… other variables
<Variables>
```

Another attempt to override empty with 0 gives the same empty cell result.

```
<Variable Name="varTotalBudget">
<Value>=
        CDbl(
            IIF(
            IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!ProjectId.Value, Fields!ACTIVITY.Value, Fields!TOTAL_BUDGET.Value, "dsActivityBudgets")), 0
            , Lookup(Fields!ProjectId.Value, Fields!ACTIVITY.Value, Fields!TOTAL_BUDGET.Value, "dsActivityBudgets"))
        )
</Value>
</Variable>
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping a SUM function around whatever expression is in the first Future Outlay cell?

Comment: @StevenWhite - The Future Outlay table cell has a value expression of `Variables!varProjectFutureOutlay.Value` and the variable value is `IIF(Variables!varBudgetVariance.Value < 0 OR IsNothing(Variables!varBudgetVariance.Value), 0, Variables!varBudgetVariance.Value)`.  When I add SUM() wrapper around either the Variable or the Tablix cell I get this error message: **`The value expression... contains a variable reference in the argument to an aggregate function (or RunningValue).  Variable values cannot be used in aggregate functions.`**.